# Swift4: How to set top constraint when you have a navigation controller?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, constraints

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Ngn.png)
I created a view where I put an image view and a view. I  programmatically added constraints to both my views so that they are perfectly centred in each screen I chose, but when I launch the app on iPhone XSMax I get a white bar in the bottom. So I guess I'm making a mistake with my top constraint, how do I handle top constraints when I have a navigation bar?

```
 func imageAndColorView() {

    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.addSubview(colorView)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    colorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    colorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    colorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    colorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    colorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: BackgroundImageKey)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
    view.insertSubview(colorView, aboveSubview: imageView)
}
```

Yes, I called this in my viewDidLoad.

Comment: Add a screenshot with your issue

Comment: Can you please try to call this function in viewDidAppear.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR done

Comment: @ManojRlogical why would it work? There's an issue in my code

Comment: The thing is, that using your code in a new project, setting colorView's bg color and running on an XSMax in iOS12 gives a different result than your screenshot (it fills the view top to bottom entirely). What is your setup?

Comment: BTW you could just swap the two first lines in order to avoid reordering in the last two (although you already have the correct ordering - so the last two lines in your code are redundant right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iphoneX above you should use **safeAreaLayoutGuide** in the **topAnchor and bottomAnchor**.
[image]

```
func imageAndColorView() {

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(colorView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        colorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        colorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        colorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        colorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: BackgroundImageKey)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
        view.insertSubview(colorView, aboveSubview: imageView)
    }
```

just replace your function with this code it'll look like this and I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: In fact, it is the opposite... The OP wants to _avoid_ (as in, do not use) safe areas and fill the whole view.

Comment: then don't give safeAreaLayoutGuide in bottomAnchor

Comment: I have another question, can I set some constraints programmatically and others in storyboard?